# A^t * A won't work in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication, transpose

I'm trying get       A^T * A.
but if I try it, I get the error

```
Error using  * MTIMES is not fully supported for integer classes. 
At least one input must be scalar. To compute elementwise TIMES, use TIMES (.*) instead.
```

so I did A^T .* A and it gave me the error

`Matrix dimensions must agree.`

I don't get it? shouldn't ATA work fine?

A is

```
A = imread('C:\Users\user1\Documents\MATLAB\5\assignment05_A.jpg');
A = rgb2gray(A);
```

before trying the multiplication

How do i get a A^T * A matrix??

Comment: Can we have the data? Note that `A^T` won't work, you'll have to use `A'` or `transpose(A)`

Comment: Please post the exact code you executed that generated the error.

Comment: Note that `.*` and `*` perform completely different operations!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to an array of double precision with [`double`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) then plot with [`imshow`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html);

```
A = double(rgb2gray(A));
ATA = A'*A;
imshow(ATA,[]);
```

Comment: I need to plot the picture again tho. 
I tried your way but the image was now a lot different. :( 
Do you know any other way?

Comment: @joonor23 `imread` returns a value between 0 and 255 for each component of `rgb`, and I guess `rgb2gray` will return a single grayscale value, again between 0 and 255. Hope that helps

Comment: @joonor23 plot the image as `imshow(yourimage,[])` and you will see it.

Comment: imshow worked! I was using imagesc and after the rgb2gray the image was all yellow. now it works! thank you guys!! :)